# Unable to find a target named `GithubProfile`

Tags: swift, cocoapods

This is my first time using CocoaPods for a swift project. I have made a new  project and successfully installed CocoaPods.  I then navigated to my project directory through the terminal and I successfuly executed the `pod init` command and then modified and saved the Podfile.  The problem presents itself when I then try to run the `pod install` command.  I recive the following error: `[!] Unable to find a target named 'GithubProfile'`.  I've looked at many tutorials and in none of them was there a file in the project folder called GithubProfile, so I am unsure exactly where this file is supposed to be located.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are the contents of your Podfile? Are you trying to create a CocoaPod or use an existing CocoaPod?

Comment: Cocoapods builds the code into static library (.a), I doubt that you couldn't use it in swift project. Why not using `Carthage` instead?

Comment: Please post what you put in your Podfile

Comment: @PaulBeusterien As it turns out, I followed the tutorials a little too well.  I wasn't thinking and in the Podfile I set it to target GithubProfile thinking that was what it was supposed to do since that what the tutorial had listed, but I should have paid more attention and realized that its supposed to target your actual project.  I fixed the mistake, thanks for nudging me on that path!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the podfile syntax.
Have a look [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html) or [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156971/cocoapods-tutorial-swift-getting-started) for more details.